# Help with buttonWatcher adding Characters to an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JButton[] buttons;
    private ArrayList<Character> playerSequence; 
    private static final Character firstChar = 'A';
    private static final Character lastChar = 'D';
    /** Creates a new instance of ButtonPanel */
    public ButtonPanel()
    {
        buttons = new JButton[4];
        playerSequence = new ArrayList<Character>();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2)); 
        Character label = firstChar;
        for (JButton b: buttons)
        {
            b = new JButton("" + label);
            buttons[label - firstChar]= b;
            b.setActionCommand("" + label);
            label++;
            add(b);
            //adds an action listener to all 4 buttons
            b.addActionListener(new ButtonWatcher());  
        }

        setButtonsEnabled(true);
    }


public class ButtonWatcher implements ActionListener
{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b)
   {
      Object clicked = b.getActionCommand();
      if(clicked.equals("1"))
      {
        playerSequence.add('A');
      }
      if(clicked.equals("2"))
      {
          playerSequence.add('B');
      }
      if(clicked.equals("3"))
      {
         playerSequence.add('C');
      }
      if(clicked.equals("4"))
      {
         playerSequence.add('D');
      }

   }
}
}
```

I am trying to get this code so when one of the buttons 1-4 is clicked it adds A-D to the arrayList playerSequence, and as far as i can see it isnt happening. Have i missed something out?

Comment: Why do you think that this isn't happening?  None of the code you've posted uses the `ArrayList`.

Comment: How do you know it isn't happening?

Comment: Is the if statement not using the ArrayList playerSequence to add the chars to it?

Comment: @user445714- It's hard to know without us actually executing the code and debugging it.  Can you provide the code that actually uses the ArrayList so we can check that the problem isn't there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your IF statements are checking for the wrong actionCommand string.
You set the actionCommand of each button to the characters 'A'-'D' but your IF statements check for '1'-'4'

Comment: Thank you so much that was a very silly error on my part have to think more simple when im looking for what ive done wrong instead of going for the bigger problems. Thanks again